# What's the proper way to include Entity Framework connection string used in WCF service into a self hosting console application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf, connection-string

I'm doing my homework, a WCF service that uses SQL Server with Entity Framework, hosted through a console application, and using a WPF client.

There are 3 different projects, and the host and the service is in the same solution. I've included the Entity Framework connection string in the console hosts' `app.config` file from the `web.config` file from the service. This way the server and the host throw an exception when I try to make a query:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 'The underlying provider failed on Open.'

The inner exception says:

> SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\username\source\repos\BlogAppWcf\BlogHost\bin\Debug\BlogDb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

So it basically searches for the `.mdf` file in it's own project folder, while it's inside the service's `App_Data` folder.

The original connection string looks like this, I copied this to the host's `app.config` from the `web.config`:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/BlogDbEntities.csdl|res://*/BlogDbEntities.ssdl|res://*/BlogDbEntities.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;
data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\BlogDb.mdf;
integrated security=True;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

I've tried modifying the `AttachDbFilename` attribute in the `app.config`, I gave it an absolute path like this:

```
attachdbfilename=C:\Users\username\source\repos\BlogAppWcf\BlogAppWcf\App_Data\BlogDb.mdf;
```

and this way it works like a charm! No more exceptions on queries.

But this isn't the right way to do it, especially because I have to send it to my teacher. I want to give it a relative path, just like this:

```
attachdbfilename=..\..\..\BlogAppWcf\App_Data\BlogDb.mdf;
```

but it doesn't work this way.

Has anyone got any suggestions, maybe I'm doing or thinking something completely wrong?

Comment: Have you asked your teacher? I don’t mean to be difficult, it’s just that they would be more likely to have a ready answer than a bunch of strangers on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description and the issue you encountered, I think the problem boils down to the fact that the attached database is not properly attached to VS built-in database server instance. For this reason, I think we could configure the EntityFramework with VS built-in database instance string.

> Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MyStore;Integrated
>   Security=True;Connect
>   Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False

And then override the seed method of the DropCreateDatabaseAlways/DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges class to provide the seed data.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.